# string query in a function in kdb

Tags: kdb

```
func:{[query] value query};
```

query is part of my function. I have add some like delete xxx, yyyy from (value query) and some manipulation. I am not sure why when I don't use value "query", the function doesn't work. It said it cannot find the table. So I have to use value query in the function and query is a parameter. I need to pass "select from tab" to the function.

My questions is: how do I send if the filter is a string too?

```
func["select from tab where a="abc""] <<< this does not work
```

How can I make string inside a string work?

Also, not sure why if I do

```
func["select from tab where date = max date"]  it did not work due to length error
but func["100#select from tab where date = max date"] it works ?
```

The whole function is

```
getTable:{[query]loadHDB[];.Q.view date where date < .z.D-30;tab:(delete xxxx,yyyyy,sub,ID,subID,tID,subTID,text,gID from((value query)));remove[];update {";"sv @[s;where (s:";"vs x) like "cId=*";:;enlist""]}each eData from (update {";"sv @[s;where (s:";"vs x) like "AId=*";:;enlist""]}each eData from tab)}; 


remove:{[]delete tab from `.};
loadHDB:{[]value "\\l /hdb};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape the quotes using backslash  http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/BackSlash#escape

```
func["select from tab where a like \"abc\""]
```

Edit:

If tab is a HDB table then this length error could point to a column length issue (which 100# is avoiding). What does the following return?

```
q)checkPartition:{[dt] a!{c!{count get x} each ` sv' x,/:c:({x where not x like "*#"} key[x])except `.d}each a:(` sv' d,/:key[d:hsym `$string dt])};
q)check:checkPartition last date
q)(where{1<count distinct value x}each check)#check
```

Comment: nice it worked! but do you know why when I did the query in the function it gave length error. If I don't specify how many records I want from the query there is error. I don't see any wrong from my function though

Comment: If tab is a HDB table then this length error could point to a column length issue (which 100# is avoiding). What does the following (moved code to edited answer)

Comment: oh if i remove #check, it returns nth

Comment: i also fount out, if i put a condition, so only eData in cols tab, it runs the function you gave me in another thread if not just return tab. Then the function works in a much better way.

Comment: it returns ()!()

Comment: Are you sure it is a length error on this line? q)func["select from tab where date = max date"]

Could you try specifying the columns you need instead? func["select a,b,c from .."]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146192/discussion-between-connor-gervin-and-terry).

Comment: Hi Connor, sorry the chat is blocked in the company. func["select from tab"] returns lenth error same thing when specifying where date = max date. but ["select col from tab"] returns something. I changed the function a little bit. so if there is no eData column in the return table, the function to replace the value will not be executed.  Not sure if it has length error cuz of the replacing value function in eData column.  I can open chat when i'm home. Thanks Connor

Answer (score 1):

I like using -3! and also -1 to print the result. If you know what your query should look like if executed from the console then after you construct your string, use -1 to print the string. It should print the query as how it would be executed by the console.

```
    q)stst:-3!
    q)"select max age by user from tab where col1 like ",stst"Hello"
    "select max age by user from tab where col1 like \"Hello\""
    q)/then to view how it will be executed, use -1
    q)-1"select max age by user from tab where col1 like ",stst"Hello";
    select max age by user from tab where col1 like "Hello"
    q)/looks good
```

Comment: Be careful with console size.. :)
q)system"c 50 10"
q)-3!"Hello"
"\"Hell..